# How can I add a subquery in JOIN

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make a join like

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity as c
 INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cv ON (c.entity_id = cv.entity_id) and(cv.attribute_id = 
 (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name'))
```

How can I add this in a join in magento with collection?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific query:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

If you want to have more control over the subquery, the following question should help you:

- [Subquery in a collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/subquery-in-a-collection/6615#6615)